# How to play a pcm audio with web audio api?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, pcm

Tody I just try play a pcm audio witch chrome browser, so I look for some API with WEB Audio, That was which I find it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.decodeAudioData. Then I write an eg with it. The java script file code is :

```
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urlList = urlList;
    this.onload = callback;
    this.bufferList = new Array();
    this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
    // Load buffer asynchronously
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    var loader = this;

    request.onload = function() {
        // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
        loader.context.decodeAudioData(
            request.response,
            function(buffer) {
                if (!buffer) {
                    alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                    return;
                }
                loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
                if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
                    loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
            }
        );
    }

    request.onerror = function() {
        alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    }

    request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
        this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}

window.onload = init;
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function init() {
    try {
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        context = new AudioContext();
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }

    bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
        context,
        [
            'http://localhost:91/learn/audio'
        ],
        finishedLoading
    );

    bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = bufferList[0];
    source.loop = true;             
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

Here is server core width servlet download:

```
@WebServlet(name = "audioServlet", urlPatterns = "/audio")
public class AudioServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        ServletOutputStream stream = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf = null;

        File pcmFile = new File("D:/2033.pcm");

        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=2033.pcm");
        resp.setContentType("audio/basic");
        resp.setContentLength((int) pcmFile.length());

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pcmFile);
        try {
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            stream = resp.getOutputStream();
            int readBytes = 0;
            //read from the file; write to the ServletOutputStream
            while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
                stream.write(readBytes);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new ServletException(ioe.toString());
        } finally {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.close();
            if (buf != null)
                buf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I browse this html file in chrome, it dosen't player any voices, and that hasn't any wrong when it's run. Also I try an mp3 or ogg audio file , It can work best. Why? Who can help me solve. The pcm audio file you can download it on : http://pan.baidu.com/s/1XAhC

Comment: Make sure your file is in supported format - https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video

Comment: Thanks, I have check file format in your provide website, the pcm format is 8-bit, but why it can't play??